# Oracle open connection wont work on other computer

Tags: c#, oracle

Have problem when run application on other PC, wont open connection. But work correctly on work station. Tested problem on two different computer.

Using NuGet: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.

Have exception:"Network Transport: TCP transport address connect failure".

CODE:

```
        string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXXXXXXXX)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = XXXXXXXXX)(SERVER = DEDICATED)));"+
        "User Id=XXXXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXXX;Persist Security Info=True;Pooling=true;"+
        "Min Pool Size=10;Connection Lifetime=240;Connection Timeout=480;" +
        "Incr Pool Size=5; Decr Pool Size=2";

        OracleConnection oracleConnection = new OracleConnection();
        oracleConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

        try
        {
            oracleConnection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            menuController.authenticationForm.AddLogs(new string[1] { ex.Message });
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: while Im no oracle guru, the address is the name resolvable from the other machine? can you connect to it through odbc for example?

Comment: All working and connecting fine until move application on other PC.

Comment: Sounds like a network problem. Did you check your firewall settings?

Comment: yeah what the others have said, you can ping the db server, XXXXXXXXX, from this new machine?

Comment: Yes, i tried to disable firewall and this dont help. When ping server by cmd, ping works fine.

Comment: Problem was that port was blocked out of working network.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but I had a similar issue where I had to use a fully qualified Service Name for our network:

On my workstation this worked fine:
    SERVICE_NAME = MyGisDatabase

For other workstation:
    SERVICE_NAME = MyGisDatabase.xx.xxxxxxx.net